# Closure of a non-monotonic set is non-monotonic?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

$S\subset \mathbb R^n$ is said to be a non-monotonic set if for no $x,y\in S$: $x>y$.

We say $x>y$ if $x_i\geq y_i$ for all $i$ and $x\neq y$.

Prove or disprove: cl$(S)$ is also non-monotonic.

**My try to prove:**

Suppose contrary. Some point $x\in bd(S)$ and $y\in cl(S)$ we have that $x>y$.

First case: $y\in int(S)$. Then let $z=\epsilon x+(1-\epsilon)y$. We have $z>y$ and $z\in S$ contradiction!!

Second case: $y\in bd(S)$. Then for some $y'\in int(S)$, either $y<y'$ or $x>y'$ (very sloppy here). This goes to case one.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: If as you say $S \in \mathbb R^n$ then $x$ is a single sequence of real numbers. In that case $x$ cannot have two members $x,y$ each of which are sequences, as implied by your referring to $x_i,y_i.$ Did you perhaps mean $S \subset \mathbb R^n$ ?

Comment: @coffeemath You are right. Sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 2):

That's false: 
$S = \{(x,-x): x \in (-\infty, 0)\} \cup 
     \{(1,0)\} \subset \mathbb R^2$
is non-monotonic.
However, $(0,0), (1,0) \in \text{cl}(S)$.

**BTW:** 
the erroneous part of your proof is, of course, the second case. The first case is trivially true, since a non-monotonic set must have empty interior.